# Binding Text From .txt File To Label

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, backbone.js

I am writing a web application that has a number of 'help' sections which are hidden until the user clicks a button. I have nearly 20+ help sections and currently is contained within individual labels.

This is making each .html file incredibly long and somewhat difficult to manage/read.

Working on a Java project some months ago, we incorporated the use of a .properties file which outline text, for example:

help1 = "Your password needs to comprise of 8 characters... etc etc";

We could then reference this .properties file.

Is there any way to do this for a web application?

Could the use of Backbone.js help? Currently i am using jQuery to toggle the visibility of the help text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use JSON to retrieve the help texts and some javascript (which doesn't even need to be in the same HTML if its size is a trouble) to assign the downloaded texts to the labels via DOM.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the require.js text plugin https://github.com/requirejs/text :

```
require(["text!some/module.html"],
    function(html) {
        //the html variable will be the text
        //of the some/module.html file
    }
);
```